# Cqrs and event sourcing on existing relational database

Tags: architecture, relational-database, cqrs, event-sourcing

We have an existing application that is written in c++ and a relational database. The application needs to be rewritten in c#, the business want some kind of tracking what has changed when by whom. CQS seems good to work for read/write, but the event sourcing seems almost impossible, because the existing app will still need to be used together with the new app. The existing c++ application uses components (data-views) that writes directly in database. 
To evolve, we would have to change all those editable tables in the c++ app to call a service to our new app with commands, which is very costly.

We need an architecture where we can evolve from the old the the new without breaking the old c++ application, and they need to work together.

An idea we have is just preparing everything for event sourcing but not using it. Then creating some tracking tables where both apps writes to. Once a block is ready, we activate that part in the new app and deactivate it in the old c++ app.

But practically then, when is the best moment to store in the existing database during the transfer? In the CommandHandler? In the EventHandler? An event UserAdded may logically only be send when the user is really added. We think making temperory commandhandlers would be the best choice.

Or any other ideas?

Comment: Do you need to know who&what has done on the legacy c++ application as well?

Comment: Yes, it's a GDPR requirement, but for legacy they say they are less strict. We don't want to take any risk, and would love to find a solution that works for both. A new idea that pop'up in the last meeging is to do all tracking pure on de SQL Server with events. The problem is that the old c++ app uses the SqlUser in the tables and not the authenticated user in the app.

Comment: Do you have a single database? Do you use transactions?

Comment: Yes a single MS SQL DB, The c++ app uses transactions sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

I think it'll be good to add triggers to SQL database and generate events for every create/update/delete.
Then just use these events for building read-model in new CQRS system.

Next you should think about what database you want, because you can use both old or new databases.
In case with old database you should update it in sagas for new CQRS app. And both apps would read from old database.
In case with new database you would have a read model or some new database like Mongo (or even SQL - it depends on size and structure of your data). Both apps would read from new database. And yes, you should change some code in old c++ app.

> An idea we have is just preparing everything for event sourcing but not using it. Then creating some tracking tables where both apps writes to. Once a block is ready, we activate that part in the new app and deactivate it in the old c++ app.

Because the plan to migrate to CQRS i suggest you to use the second way.